# How to politely say to sellers in stores that you don't need help?

Tags: phrases, idioms, word-usage, formality, politeness

This happens quite often. You're at a store, and while looking for clothes sellers come over and ask if you need any help. And since my English is far away from normal English I just use what I know ***might*** work in similar cases.

What do natives use to say politely (or why not just informally), that:

1. They are ok, and they can find it on their own?
2. They are just, kind of *watching* (I know this can't be the right
   word), probably not intending to buy anything particular at the
   moment?

Thank you!